# Angular Delete request is not working. But Postman works

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, postman

*HttpService*

```
 delete<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.delete<T>(`${url}`);
  }
```

*SettingsService*

```
deleteTeamMember(companyId: number, userId: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.httpService.delete<void>(
      `${environment.urls.api}/company/${companyId}/team/${userId}`
    );
  }
```

*component.ts*

```
 this.settingsService
          .deleteTeamMember(this.company.companyId, teamMember.userId)
          .subscribe(); //api call
```

The above API call is not working. It says 400 bad request. It has access tokens and etc too.

**API response**

```
{
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Expected one of: <<{,[>> but got: <<EOF>>",
    "type": "tag:oracle.com,2020:error/BadRequest",
    "instance": "tag:oracle.com,2020:ecid/XgKKiZB497hJdOcC1jQxOQ"
}
```

But the same API and access token are working fine with the Postman.

Do you know why?

*AuthInterceptor*

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private isRefreshing = false;

  private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(
    null
  );

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private userDataService: UserDataService
  ) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let authRequest = request;
    const accessToken = this.userDataService.getAccessToken();

    if (accessToken != null) {
      authRequest = this.addTokenHeader(request, accessToken);
    }

    return next.handle(authRequest).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        if (
          error instanceof HttpErrorResponse &&
          !authRequest.url.includes('auth/sign-in') &&
          error.status === 401
        ) {
          return this.handle401Error(authRequest, next);
        }

        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

  private handle401Error(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      const refreshToken = this.userDataService.getRefreshToken();

      if (refreshToken) {
        return this.authService.refreshToken(refreshToken).pipe(
          switchMap((token: TokenModel) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;

            this.userDataService.setAccessToken(token?.accessToken);
            this.userDataService.setRefreshToken(token?.refreshToken);

            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.accessToken); //get the 'accessToken' from refreshToken() call

            return next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, token.accessToken));
          }),
          catchError((err) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;

            this.userDataService.setIsSignedOut(true); //Sign Out the app

            return throwError(err);
          })
        );
      }
    }

    return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
      filter((accessToken) => accessToken !== null),
      take(1),
      switchMap((accessToken) =>
        next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, accessToken))
      )
    );
  }

  private addTokenHeader(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    accessToken: string
  ): HttpRequest<any> {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Token': accessToken,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Bad request is fired by the server, why not try to contact server team in order to get some logs? Why do you have a void response specified, when it is supposed to return an object with statusCode and statusMessage? What did you do first, postman or client? If postman was sent first, are you sure it is not connected to deleting the same ressource twice?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I have done this first on the Angular app and then on the Postman. So no issues there.

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but did you add the entry back in after deleting it with postman?

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Please see my comment above.

Comment: @Sampath do you have some code you're not showing? Presumably you add the access token header somehow.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I have updated the API response too.

Comment: @Sampath I do see the request `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`, could the server be trying to read an empty body? The error seems to indicate it's trying to parse some json. You could try setting that header in postman and see.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Yes, it needs an empty body. So how to fix that? I do not have any issues with other HTTP calls with the above Interceptor.

Comment: You can remove that header from your interceptor, I believe angular sets it automatically depending on the request type, delete requests shouldn't have it.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Awesome. It works. i.e removed  'Content-Type': 'application/json', . Please put this as an answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely just remove the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` from your interceptor. Angular sets this header automatically when necessary. Delete requests don't need it.

```
private addTokenHeader(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    accessToken: string
  ): HttpRequest<any> {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', // REMOVE
        'Access-Token': accessToken,
      },
    });
```